# Java 8 substract dates but keep the hour

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

I want to subtract 7 days from Now, but keeping the time, so If now is 
12/09/2018 at 18:30, get 05/09/2018 at 18:30...

I've tried:

```
public static Date subtractDays (int numDaysToSubstract) {
        LocalDate now = LocalDate.now().minusDays(numDaysToSubstract); 
        return Date.from(now.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
    }
```

But I got 05/09/2018 at 00:00

Comment: Why `LocalDate`? Why `atStartOfDay`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have suggested, `LocalDate` and `atStartOfDay` should have been red flags based on just their name. They are the wrong type to describe a time and the wrong method to maintain the time.

It's also kind of pointless to go through `LocalDateTime` to then convert it to an `Instant`. Just use an `Instant` straight up

```
public static Date subtractDays(int numDaysToSubstract) {
    return Date.from(Instant.now().minus(numDaysToSubstract, ChronoUnit.DAYS));
    // or
    // return Date.from(Instant.now().minus(Duration.ofDays(numDaysToSubstract)));

}
```

(I assume you're using `java.util.Date` because of compatibility with some old API.)

Answer (score 1):

It’s unclear from the code in the other answers posted until now how they handle summer time (DST) and other time anomalies. And they do that differently. To make it clearer that you want 18.30 last week if time now is 18.30, no matter if a transition to or from summer time has happened in the meantime I suggest using `ZonedDateTime`:

```
    System.out.println("Now:                 " + Instant.now());
    Instant aWeekAgo = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Madrid"))
            .minusWeeks(1)
            .toInstant();
    System.out.println("A week ago in Spain: " + aWeekAgo);
```

Since summer time in Spain hasn’t ended or begun within the last week, running the code snippet just now gave the same time of day also in UTC (which is what `Instant` prints):

```
Now:                 2018-09-13T09:46:58.066957Z
A week ago in Spain: 2018-09-06T09:46:58.102680Z
```

I trust you to adapt the idea to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use class `LocalDateTime` instead of `LocalDate` (which doesn't contain a time component..)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `LocalDateTime` instead of `LocalDate`

`LocalDate` is just a description of the date without time or time-zone

```
public static Date subtractDays (int numDaysToSubstract) {
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(numDaysToSubstract); 
    return Date.from(now.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Test {

    public static String subtractDays (int numDaysToSubstract) {
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(numDaysToSubstract);
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        String formatDateTime = now.format(formatter);


        return formatDateTime;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println(subtractDays(7));

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. Code only answers aren’t really helpful. We’re here to understand, so if you’d please add some explanation in your answer? Like how your code works and how it solves the asker’s issue.